# What will the spring-boot-starter-parent version that contains spring-expression version

Tags: version, spring-boot-starter-parent

What will the spring-boot-starter-parent version that contains spring-expression-6.0.7 ?
Currently I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent-3.0.2

And kindly let me know where to look

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring-boot-starter-parent 3.0.5 version for that.